# how fiter the values when joining 4 tables?

Tags: sql-server-2008

tbl_category

```
pk_int_category_id,
vchr_category_name
```

tbl_projects

```
fk_int_category_id,
pk_int_project_id,
vchr_project_name,
vchr_project_description,
bln_project_status
```

tbl_project_album

```
pk_int_album_id
fk_int_project_id
vchr_album_name
vchr_album_description
```

tbl_picture

```
fk_int_album_id,
pk_int_picture_id,
vchr_picture_name,
vchr_picture_description,
vchr_picture_path
```

Insert data to tables 
2 categories c1 and c2, 
Enter 2 or 3 projects, corresponding to each category. c1p1, c1p2, c2p1, c2p2 and so on.
There should be minimum 2 albums per project and minimum 2 pictures per album

1. Create a result set containing:

   Pk_category_id,
   category_name,
   Pk_project_id,
   project_name,
   Pk_Picture_id,
   Picture_name,
   Pk_Album_id,
   Album_name
2. Filter the result set in such a way that all the projects and, all albums and one picture corresponding to an album is displayed
3. Filter the result set in such a way that all the projects and, one picture and one album corresponding a project is displayed

Comment: Is this homework? If so, then it should be marked as such.

Comment: Homeworks are not supposed to be posted here. Try to do it by yourself. :P

Comment: so what have you tried? This isn't the let me cheat on my schoolwork site.

Answer (score -1):

```
select c.pk_int_category_id ,c.vchr_category_name,p.pk_int_project_id,p.vchr_project_name,pr.pk_int_picture_id,pr.vchr_picture_name,a.pk_int_album_id,a.vchr_album_name
from tbl_category c,tbl_projects p,tbl_project_album a, tbl_picture pr
where c.pk_int_category_id=p.fk_int_category_id and p.pk_int_project_id=a.fk_int_project_id and a.pk_int_album_id=pr.fk_int_album_id;
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and format the code to make it readable.

Answer (score -1):

Filter the result set in such a way that all the projects and, all albums and one picture corresponding to an album is displayed

`
select p.vchr_project_name,a.vchr_album_name,pr.vchr_picture_name from tbl_projects p,tbl_project_album A,tbl_picture pr where p.pk_int_project_id=a.fk_int_project_id  and a.pk_int_album_id=pr.fk_int_album_id group by a.vchr_album_name ;

Comment: Do not teach people to use implict joins. They are a SQL antipattern and should not be used in the 21st century.